# Why Elastic search bulk operation failing for large size of data

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to send  around 30MB of data in bulk method, it is breaking 
This error doesn't say much, but when data size id less its working fine I am suspecting it because of size only ?  I wnt through the ES 6.4 API doc couldn't find any such restriction, do you know why is this breaking can I set the limit

```
Elasticsearch ERROR: 2019-01-14T15:32:36Z
  Error: Request error, retrying
  POST http://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy/_bulk => read ECONNRESET
      at Log.error (D:\UBX\UBX_WS\NodeAngular\myapp\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:226:56)
      at checkRespForFailure (D:\UBX\UBX_WS\NodeAngular\myapp\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:259:18)
      at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (D:\UBX\UBX_WS\NodeAngular\myapp\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connectors\http.js:163:7)
      at ClientRequest.wrapper (D:\UBX\UBX_WS\NodeAngular\myapp\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4935:19)
      at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
      at ClientRequest.wrapped (D:\UBX\UBX_WS\NodeAngular\myapp\node_modules\newrelic\lib\transaction\tracer\index.js:181:22)
      at ClientRequest.wrappedRequestEmit (D:\UBX\UBX_WS\NodeAngular\myapp\node_modules\newrelic\lib\instrumentation\core\http-outbound.js:138:26)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
      at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

Client creation

```
this.client = new elasticsearch.Client({
                log: 'info',
                hosts: 'xxxxx',
                apiVersion: '6.4',
                keepAlive: true,
                suggestCompression: true,
                requestTimeout: 1000 * 60 * 60,
                createNodeAgent: (httpConnector, config) => {
                    let Agent = httpConnector.hand.Agent;
                    let agentConfig = httpConnector.makeAgentConfig(config);
                    agentConfig.keepAliveTimeout = 1000 * 60 * 60;
                    return new Agent(agentConfig);
                }
});


**Sending bulk data** 


ESClient.bulk({ body },
                    function (err, resp) {
                        if (err) {
                            log.error('bulkUpdateOrDelete failed with error - ', JSON.stringify(err));
                            reject(err);
                        } else {
                            log.debug('************* bulkUpdateOrDelete success with response - ', JSON.stringify(resp));
                            log.debug(JSON.stringify(resp));
                            resolve(resp);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to HTTP settings limiting the size of the request.

This setting `http.max_content_length` is defaulted to 100 Mb, so you should try to increase it in your **elasticsearch.yml**

Documentation link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: Thanks ,  the content which is breaking is of 28MB I will explicitly set and check

Comment: I am using nodejs (express) and having a elasticsearch package with same error, where should I update the `http.max_content_length` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Elasticsearch on a server in the cloud? Usually there are limits on HTTP payloads based on server size so i am assuming your instance only supports HTTP payloads < 30 MB. I experienced a similar issue on a smaller instance in AWS. Changing to a bigger instance resolved the issue.

Comment: Right, it was particularly limitation of AWS elastic